# Insert new column into dataframe as a VARIABLE

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I used the following to obtain state using zipcode

```
from uszipcode import SearchEngine
engine = SearchEngine()
zipcode = engine.by_zipcode(ZIPCODE)

**st** = print(zipcode.state)
```

Now I am trying to insert state into data frame df2:

- I can do it manually such as:

```
  df2.assign(STATE = 'Florida')
```

*Column name is STATE

- However, new data will used with this scrip so I need to use a variable. How can I do that?

  This is my unsuccessful shot:

```
df2.assign(STATE = **st**)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `print()` doesn't return anything, there's no point in assigning it to a variable.

Comment: Just use `st = zipcode.state` without `print()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show your code please but it seems that you only have to add it to the dataframe.

```
zipcode = zipcode.state  # Florida in this case
df2['STATE']= zipcode
```

Answer (score 0):

df['new_column'] = 'some value'

You can do the following:

pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

where df1 is your dataframe and df2 is your new column.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).